# using artifact in next job which will run on a ssh runner in gitlab fails

Tags: npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using gitlab self-managed version 14.6. I defined 2 jobs in `.gitlab-ci.yaml` pipeline file: build and deploy. simply, build job runs in a docker executor on gitlab-runner and produces `build/` artifact, containing nodejs codes, which is available on gitlab-runner server working directory. I want to use this artifact in next job, where I use an **ssh executor** to provide web content, in fact ssh-executor is a remote nginx server. But, when gitlab runs `cp build/ /to/ssh/executor/path` fail with this error:    `cp: cannot stat ‘src/build’: No such file or directory`

here is my pipeline yaml configs:

```
build react job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - npm install 
        - npm run build --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - build/
        untracked: true
deploy on production:
    stage: deploy
    tags:
        - my-srv  # this is ssh-executor runner
    rules:
        - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develope")
    script:
        - cp -r build /path/on/my/server/web/content
        - docker-compose up -d
    needs:
        - job: build react job
          artifacts: true
```

As it is clear, I tried `dependencies:` and also `needs` sections to relate deploy stage to build stage. however, none of them worked. Below is *my-srv* runner configs in `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "my-srv"
  url = "http://gitlab.example.com/"
  token = "s8XljhkxJd-qj7WxCcew"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "user"
    password = "pass"
    host = "172.20.ip.addr"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Hi Just wondering if you have worked this out?

Answer (score 1):

Your pipeline code doesn't look broken, and [artifact sharing is supported for SSH executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/index.html#compatibility-chart), thus some debugging would be in order. Here's what I would do to figure out what goes wrong:

First, lose the `untracked: true` statement, you probably don't need it. The artifacts you actually use in later jobs are already covered by `paths:` statement, and adding `untracked: true` only adds other files untracked by `git` to the list of artifacts -- this could be your `npm` build cache, installed modules and so on. Most likely you don't want them, and it *really* affects the job execution time.

Second, your `deploy on production` job runs on remote system `172.20.ip.addr`, and the error message you're getting says that the `src/build` dir is not there - which can have three possible reasons:

1. `build` dir was not uploaded to Gitlab server as an artifact.
2. `build` dir was never copied to the remote system by the Gitlab (which would make it a bug?)
3. `build` dir was copied, but to a different destination directory, or you refer to it from an unexpected location (i.e. where does `src/` part come from?)

(1) is easy to check: the artifacts should be browseble from the right side of the job details page, like this:
[image]

(2) can be verified using a third job:

```yaml
check-artifacts:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
    - job: build react job
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - echo "Checking if 'build' dir is made available by Gitlab..."
    - ls -lart $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build
    - find $CI_PROJECT_DIR -type d -name build
```

If this job is executed by the same runner as the `build react job` and it could find your `build` dir, then the artifact itself is fine. Check the green lines at the start of this job's log to make sure Gitlab tried downloading artifacts.

(3) can be tested similarly to (2):

```yaml
deploy on production:
  stage: deploy
  tags:
    - my-srv  # this is ssh-executor runner
  rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develope")
  before_script:
    - echo "Running as user $USER on host $HOSTNAME in dir $PWD"
    - find $CI_PROJECT_DIR -type d -name build    # try looking in the civilized location first...
    - find / -type d -name build 2>/dev/null      # ... but maybe it's elsewhere
  script:
    - cp -r build /path/on/my/server/web/content
    - docker-compose up -d
  needs:
    - job: build react job
      artifacts: true
```

If commands in `before_script` section fail while the helper job we used above succeeds, it would look like a bug of sharing the artifacts with SSH executor-based runners. If the helper job fails, there's something wrong with artifact upload/download/sharing in general, look at the Gitlab logs to see if you find anything relevant.

Comment: thanks for detailed procedure you've suggested. step1) is passed successfully with message `Uploading artifacts...` so the artifact is created and cached. step2) is passed successfully but only on docker executor nor ssh executor which I aimed. the message on docker executor is `Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok`. step3) however, always throw this warning: `Missing gitlab-runner. Artifacts downloading is disabled.` that is to say, artifact is not downloaded on remote server

Comment: Right, this narrows it down. I checked the [SSH executor documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/ssh.html), and there's this statement there: _"If you want to upload job artifacts, install gitlab-runner on the host you are connecting to via SSH."_
Maybe downloading artifacts requires that too, in which case it's a documentation bug. In any case I would try installing the Gitlab Runner to the target host (maybe limited to a dedicated user), and see if artifact sharing works. If it doesn't, I'd be inclined to open an issue on Gitlab's issue tracker.